# On Table row click, show me new page with data from only that row! Can someone direct me how to do that

Tags: html, hyperlink, row

No need to explain. Imagine simple table with same data. When you just click on a table row, it's open a new page with just that row shown.

Comment: Give unique id to each row and depending on that id show data in dialog

Answer (score 0):

you can bind click event on the table ....

```
function showRowDetails(event){
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.body.innerHTML="<table border='1'>"+event.target.parentNode.innerHTML+"</table>";
}
```

HTML

```
<table border="1" onclick="showRowDetails(event)">
   <tr>...</tr>...
</table>
```

or you can also show a popup div instead of opening a new window...